# I want to load two browser windows one below the other in a one form in Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to have two different browser windows loaded one below the other on the same form in Visual studio. I can load one browser window and keep it half way up top, with sizes and locations specified. When I add a second browser window below the first one, I am missing something. I am not a programmer, just learning. So, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowser();
            InitBrowser2();

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }


    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser1;
    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        browser1 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/");
        this.Controls.Add(browser1);
        browser1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        browser1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top);
        browser1.Size = new Size(1300, 400);
    }

    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser2;
    public void InitBrowser2()
    {
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        browser2 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.yahoo.com/");
        this.Controls.Add(browser2);
        browser2.Location = new Point(0, 400);
        browser2.Size = new Size(1300, 400);
    }
```

when I load only the

```
 InitBrowser1();
```

inside the

```
 public Form() {}
```

it loads.
but when i put the

```
  InitBrowser2();
```

only the first one shows up, not the second one. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way that I can have two browser windows loaded on one form?

Edit: I found a way to load both browsers on one form. I changed the code as below. The only problem now is they do not align properly, they show overlapping on each other. Any help on how to have one on the top half of the page and the other to the bottom half of the page?

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser2;
    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());

        browser1 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/");
        this.Controls.Add(browser1);
        browser1.Location = new Point(-300, 0);
        browser1.Size = new Size(1300, 400);

        browser2 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.yahoo.com");
        this.Controls.Add(browser2);
        browser2.Location = new Point(-300, 400);
        browser2.Size = new Size(300, 400);

    }
```

Comment: If you have just the browser2, does it show up?  (Comment out the InitBrowser();)

Comment: InitBrowser2() then InitBrowser().  Does 2 show up and 1 not?

Comment: Yes it does, but in full view as if I gave browser2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

Comment: When I put the InitBrowser2(); and then InitBrowser(); as jeromeyers asked, It throws error        "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in CefSharp.Core.dll

Additional information: Cef can only be initialized once. Use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against this exception."

Comment: Then I tried changing the "Initialize" in InitBrowser2(); it says " 'CefSharp.Cef' does not contain a definition for 'initialized' ".

Comment: Thanks all for trying to help, I found a way of loading both browsers on the same form, but now I need help in keeping one on the top half of the page and the other on the bottom half of the page. I have edited the question to add the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for trying to help out, you questions for clarification made me look for the errors and come up with a solution. Now I can load both browsers one below the other on the same Windows.Form. Below is the working code.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitBrowser();          
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser1;
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser2;

    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());

        browser1 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/");
        this.Controls.Add(browser1);
        browser1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top;
        browser1.Location = new Point(-300, 0);
        browser1.Size = new Size(1300, 500);

        browser2 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.yahoo.com");
        this.Controls.Add(browser2);
        browser2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top;
        browser2.Location = new Point(-300, 500);
        browser2.Size = new Size(1300, 200);

    }
```