# Document.getElementById() not available for ChromiumWebBrowser in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-chrome

When I open a browser as

```
WebBrowser browser1;
```

I am able to call

```
browser1.Document.getElementById();
```

but when I load the browser as

```
CromiumWebBrowser browser1;
```

it says "CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser does not contain a definition for document".

I have loaded a google sheet on a Chromium browser. I simply want to enter "something" on the first cell.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working out to load two browsers in one form [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929344/i-want-to-load-two-browser-windows-one-below-the-other-in-a-one-form-in-visual-s), I just had to copy the value and paste it to the focused area on the second browser. That's the best I could do.

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject((value).ToString(), true);
browser2.Paste();
```

but now I need to solve another thing.
I need to select the next cell on a google sheet. And I have created [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009572/how-to-select-the-next-cell-in-google-sheet-from-visual-studio-solution-project)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
browser1.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.GetElementById('id1');");
```