# how to select the next cell in google sheet from visual studio solution project?

Tags: visual-studio, google-apps-script

I had worked out a way to display google sheet with chromiumbrowser in a solution project in visual studio. I had it automatically paste value to the selected cell [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931476/document-getelementbyid-not-available-for-chromiumwebbrowser-in-visual-studio).

Now I need to figure a way out to select the next cell in the sheet.

so far I could not find an ID, Class or Xpath for a particular cell. Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code? You can check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).

Comment: No I couldn't. As an alternative, I loaded a google doc, and then had the program paste values onto the doc, and then copied those from the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loaded the googlesheet in a second browser and then then had the program copy the values and paste to the google sheet, by copytoclipboard and paste. That was the solution I could arrive on.

I could not find a way to select the next cell in googlesheet via c#.